# Batch Variable from text file with space

Tags: batch-file

So I recently came up with a problem. I have used the same code for a long time, but when I tried to make it possible for variables to contain spaces it just crashes...
Here is my normal code:

```
set INPUT=TEST TEST
for /f "Delims=" %%a in (E:\Test\%INPUT%.TEST) do (

set ANSWER=%%a
)
```

but because the INPUT is `TEST TEST` it crashes and says couldn't find `"E:\Test\TEST"`.
When I tried to make some changes and add `""` in the code:

```
set INPUT=TEST TEST
for /f "Delims=" %%a in ("E:\Test\%INPUT%.TEST") do (

set ANSWER=%%a
)
```

But when it said couldn't find `"E:\Test\TEST TEST.TEST"`.
And It should just find `E:\Test\TEST TEST.TEST` not `"E:\Test\TEST TEST.TEST"`.
or `E:\Test\TEST`.

Please help.. *(I'm sorry if the "TEST" word is everywhere... xD)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```bat
Set "INPUT=TEST TEST"
For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%A In ("E:\Test\%INPUT%.TEST"
) Do Set "ANSWER=%%A"
```

Comment: Thanks Compo! It worked and I can now return to work on my project! :D Thank you very much!